Custom UserControl inside ItemsControl.DataTemplate
I have the following window:
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApp1="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        Title="MyApp" Height="450" Width="300">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <wpfApp1:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ComboBox Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay}">

                        </ComboBox>
                        <Button Content="Delete" 
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

        <Button Content="Add New"
                Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

And the code-behind:
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

My view model:
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataEntry> Values { get; set; }
    public List<MyEnum> Items => GetItems();
    public ICommand AddCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Values = new ObservableCollection<DataEntry>();
        AddCommand = new RelayCommand(AddComboBox);
        DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand<DataEntry>(DeleteComboBox);
    }

    private void AddComboBox()
    {
        Values.Add(new DataEntry(MyEnum.None));
    }

    private void DeleteComboBox(DataEntry entry)
    {
        if (Values.Contains(entry))
        {
            Values.Remove(entry);
        }
    }

    private List<MyEnum> GetItems()
    {
        return Enum.GetValues<MyEnum>().ToList();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

And this is the code for DataEntry and MyEnum:
public enum MyEnum
{
    First,
    Second,
    Third,
    None
}

public class DataEntry
{
    public MyEnum Data { get; set; }

    public DataEntry(MyEnum data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}

This works as intended: I can add and remove comboboxes using buttons and changes to selected items of comboboxes will be reflected in Values collection. What I want now is to move content of ItemsSource DataTemplate to a separate UserControl (mostly for learning purposes).
I defined it as following:
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"></local:MainViewModel>
    </UserControl.Resources>    

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}">
        <ComboBox Width="150" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyControl}}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button Content="Delete" 
                Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>

Code-behind:
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(SelectedItem),                                   
            typeof(object),                                        
            typeof(MyControl),                                   
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get => GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
    }
}

And changed DataTemplate to:
<wpfApp1:MyControl SelectedItem="{Binding Data, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

It works for adding comboboxes and for modifying their selected items. But deleting causes an exception:
Unable to cast object of type 'WpfApp1.MyEnum' to type 'WpfApp1.DataEntry'
Which makes sense because I pass Data property of the DataEntry to my control, so it doesn't know anything about the DataEntry where this Data is stored and therefore can't pass is as a parameter to the command.
I've tried to change my binding to:
<wpfApp1:MyControl SelectedItem="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay}"/>

So from my understanding now I'm binding object of type DataEntry to the SelectedItem property. However, an exception still occurs upon deleting items. Also changing selected items in comboboxes no more update Values collection in this case.
So the question is: how to properly setup binding for my custom user control to retain initial functionality?

Are you aware that you are creating multiple instances of MainViewModel? There is one instance in MainWindow and one per UserControl instance, i.e. one per element in the Value collection. That is most certainly not what you want, so you have to remove the MainViewModel resource from the UserControl's XAML and not set the StackPanel's DataContext there.

The UserControl would have to expose additional properties for the Items and DeleteCommand Bindings, so that all Bindings in its XAML use RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}.

Oh that's interesting. I tought I'm referencing my ViewModel, not creating another one. Thank you for clarifying

Use a UC, or a Datatemplate; not both (IMO). The UC, in effect, is already a template. Using both, you now have to untangle the binding of the template, through the UC, to the data source. And the UC could be tangled mess to start with.
